# ionic rest http problems

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-http

```
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  post(serviceName:string,date:any){
      const data = {};
      const headers= new HttpHeaders();
      const option = { header: headers, widthCredintials:false };
      const url = environment.apiUrl + serviceName;
      return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data),option);
  }
}
```

error:No Overload matches this call option

please help me what can ı do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check below example hope this working

```
post(serviceName:string,date:any){
          const data = {};
          const headers= new HttpHeaders();
          const url = environment.apiUrl + serviceName;
          return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data),{ headers, withCredentials: false });
      }
```